# Cimg in embedded hardware

Tags: image-processing

I load a jpg into embedded system memory on an Stm32 board with assembly code via .incbin and copy the data to an alternate buffer via std::copy. The image is displayed on an attached lcd screen and is decompressed with picoimage and all is well. I wish to apply image effects beforehand and I use CImg which seems to be small and portable. Compared to others I simply have to place the header in working directory and I have a grayscale code below; however, I have to same issue as when I attempted to alter the code by hand the screen appears black. I can't seem to find a proper fix for it. Are their any suggestions. For some reason I feel as though CImg is not aware it is a jpg file and opts to load and operate on the whole compressed data. Is their a work around?

```
CImg<uint8_t> image(_buffer,_panel->getWidth(),_panel->getHeight(),1,1,true);

        int width = image.width();
        int height = image.height();
        //int depth = image.depth();

        //New grayscale images.
        //CImg<unsigned char> gray1(width,height,depth,1);
        //CImg<unsigned char> gray2(width,height,depth,1);


        unsigned char r,g,b;
        unsigned char gr1 = 0;
        unsigned char gr2 = 0;

        /* Convert RGB image to grayscale image */
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){

                //Return a pointer to a located pixel value.
                r = image(i,j,0,0); // First channel RED
                g = image(i,j,0,1); // Second channel GREEN
                b = image(i,j,0,2); // Third channel BLUE


                //PAL and NTSC
                //Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
                gr1 = round(0.299*((double)r) + 0.587*((double)g) + 0.114*((double)b));

                //HDTV
                //Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
                gr2 = round(0.2126*((double)r) + 0.7152*((double)g) + 0.0722*((double)b));

                image(i,j,0,0) = gr1;
                //image(i,j,0,0) = gr2;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

cimg does not decompress jpeg images itself, it uses your system jpeg library. If you are using a debian-derivative, for example, you'll need `apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev` before compiling. Have a look through cimg and make sure it's picking up the headers and linking correctly.